# Website naming conventions

Tags: html, css

Is there a standard way I should be naming my element's IDs and classes. Recently I have been looking into cleaning up all my CSS (NIGHTMARE!) and I have been seeing a lot of different schemes for naming. I am using camel casing for mine but I have been seeing, in my adventure to organize, hyphened selectors, capitals at the start of every new "selector word", and much more. I also use dang near whole words for my selectors.
So should it be:

rightContent

right-content

RightContent

or is it really personnel preference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is completely personal preference, but there is one thing you should do: **be consistent with what you choose.**

Comment: I decided to go with getting rid of my camel casings way (in CSS only) thanks to the following article:
[CSS Wizardy](http://csswizardry.com/2010/12/css-camel-case-seriously-sucks/)

Pretty much states that CSS is a majority (hyphenized??-wordcheck) naming convention. So why change it.

Answer (score 2):

As [Delan Azabani said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870803/website-naming-conventions/6870827#6870827), it boils down to consistently applied personal choice.

Larger projects tend to formalise their project's coding standards, which also include naming conventions (usually of far more than just CSS) - that's the point you need to adhere to (possibly) someone else's personal choice. For example, [Zend's framework has some (not-CSS) publically available](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html), to give you an idea of how such an agreement might look.

Something like that *can* pay off the minute you have more than one developer - to just sit down and agree on a Definite Way To Do It <sup>TM</sup>. But if you're the sole developer, just pick a flavour and run with it.